# Powershell Form IP Address textbox validation

Tags: validation, powershell, textbox

I'm trying to create a text box for IP address input (eg. 000.000.000.000) via a Windows Powershell gui using Sapien Powershell Studio.

I looked into Maskedtextbox but it doesn't display so well (the _) and I can't limit the range (up to 255) on input.

I've also looked into NumericUpDown which would be perfect if I could hide the arrows as it gives me the ability to limit the range and sets to numbers only.

If not possible to restict on input, I'm thinking of just having 4 text boxes with a MaxLength=3 and a "TextChanged" event validation to wipe text if it not numeric or within range.

Am I overlooking an easier/better way?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to be too smart with your text box, allow your users to enter the IP address without having to fiddle with up/down arrows etc, let them input in a free-form way. They'll thank you for this.

Then upon submission of your form or perhaps exiting the field try to parse the IP address by doing something like:

```
$ip_address = $null
$a = [System.Net.IPAddress]::TryParse($ip_address_to_validate, [ref]$ip_address)
if ($ip_address -ne $null)
{
    # It's valid
}
else
{
    # Not valid - display an error message on form
}
```

Comment: Cheers, agreed. I was looking to hide the up/down arrows if using the NumericUpDown. I noticed there is an option on the textbox properties > Data > Formatting and Advanced Binding which has "Format type" which could allow me to set the Format type to Numeric but is greyed out. Any idea how to change/enable this setting? Then I could at least prevent letter characters at the input and do a validation action on textchanged or exitting field to limit the range entered to 255.

Comment: I guess you could trap these characters using KeyDown or KeyPress events.The Data/Bindings stuff is for when you are using data-bound controls and wish to format field values from a data source such as SQL or Access (been a while since I did WinForms development).

Answer (score 1):

Personaly I agree with @Kev, but I use a regular expression for that.

```
$regip=[regex]"^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$"
$regip.IsMatch("10.1.1.10")
```